# Chaining shell commands golang

Tags: mongodb, shell, go, exec, mongo-shell

I'm trying to run a shell script from my go program. I want to start up a `mongo` instance and then remove some data. So the shell script would look something like this:

```
mongo

use test-db

db.user.remove({"id": 1})
```

I initially tried just using the `exec.Command` package but it doesn't chain the commands so the mongo db closes and I can't run the other commands:

```
cmd := exec.Command("mongo", "test-db")
cmd.Start()
cmd1 := exec.Command("db.remove({\"id\": 1})")
cmd1.Run()
cmd.Wait()
```

The next thing I tried is creating a variable and trying to execute that via sh:

```
var script = `
 #!/bin/bash

mongo

use test-db

db.user.remove({"id": 1})
`
```

and executing `exec.Command("sh", script)`

I know I can create a `.sh` file but I don't want to do that is there any way to chain commands in go so the mongo db doesn't close and I can execute the other commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand how processes (such as interpreters and shells, including—[it appears](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10569)—`mongodb` as well) work with their so-called [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams): while the "test-db" is indeed an argument to pass to a `mongodb` process to be created on its command-line, the `db.user.remove({"id": 1})` is the text that spawned `mongodb` instance is supposed to read from its standard input stream.

So basically you need this:

```
import (
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

cmd := exec.Command("mongo", "test-db")
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(`db.user.remove({"id": 1})\n`)
err := cmd.Run()
// Check for an error
```

To explain how this works, let's cite the [manual](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd):

> `Stdin` specifies the process's standard input.
>   If `Stdin` is `nil`, the process reads from the null device (`os.DevNull`).
>   If `Stdin` is an `*os.File`, the process's standard input is connected
>   directly to that file.
>   Otherwise, during the execution of the command a separate
>   goroutine reads from `Stdin` and delivers that data to the command
>   over a pipe. In this case, `Wait` does not complete until the goroutine
>   stops copying, either because it has reached the end of `Stdin`
>   (EOF or a read error) or because writing to the pipe returned an error.
>   `Stdin io.Reader`

So basically you create an object which takes a string and provides *something* implementing `io.Reader` and "wire" it to the standard input of the process about to be created.
Once the process starts, `os/exec` will make sure to spawn a goroutine which will shovel data between your string and the running `mongodb` instance—as if you would start `mongodb` by hand and typed that string onto its standard input stream directly.

Note that you also might need to check what `mongodb` generates on its standard *output* streams—especially `stderr`,—because if it encounters any errors while executing the script you have submitted to it, it will likely report them there.